# Passing Radio button values from html page to html.

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working on a new security assessment webpage in which I am using HTML and Java Script. For some reason, the code is not working properly and not getting the desired results. The way the code supposed to work is by having the user answer Yes or No questions, then pass the values to throughout the 5 html pages until the last page when the user click submit.Then the page would display the number of questions answered yes.

Any help would be appreciated it.

Thanks,

```js
<script>
$('.calc').change(function() {
    calcscore();            
});
$('#submitted').click(function() {
    sumInputs();
    result();
});
function sumInputs() {
    var inputs = $('.calc:checked'), 
        result = $('#total').val(), 
        sum = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
        sum += parseInt(inputs[i].value);
    }
    $('#total').val(sum);
}
function calcscore() {
    var score = 0;
    $('.calc:checked').each(function () {                
        score += parseInt($(this).val(), 10);
    });
    $('#total').val(score);
}
</script>

-------------------------------------------------
(Last java script code) 

<script>

$('.calc').change(function() {
    calcscore();            
});

$('#submitted').click(function() {
    sumInputs();
    result();

});

function sumInputs() {
    var inputs = $('.calc:checked'), 
        result = $('#total').val(), 
        sum = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
        sum += parseInt(inputs[i].value);
    }
    $('#total').val(sum);
}

function result() {
    var text;
    var score = (( $('#total').val() ) / 57 ) * 100;
    var score = score.toFixed(1);            

    if (score < 60) {
       alert ( text = "Total score " + score + ": You have failed the Assessment");
    }
    else {            
       alert ( text = "Total score " + score + ": You have passed the Assessment");
    }

    $('#demo').text(text);
}

function calcscore() {

    var score = 0;

    $('.calc:checked').each(function () {                
        score += parseInt($(this).val(), 10);
    });

    $('#total').val(score);

}

</script>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <body>
    <table>
<th>PHYSICAL SECURITY </th>
   

  <tr>
    <td>7. Do you have policies and procedures that address allowing authorized and
limiting unauthorized physical access to electronic information systems and the
facilities in which they are housed? 

<form>
 Yes
<input class="calc" type="radio" name="radio4" value="1" /> <br />
No
<input class="calc" type="radio" name="radio4" value="0" /> <br />
N/A
<input class="calc" type="radio" name="radio4" value="0" /> <br />

</form> 
</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>8. Do your policies and procedures specify the methods used to control physical
access to your secure areas, such as door locks, access control systems,
security officers, or video monitoring?

<form>
 Yes
<input class="calc" type="radio" name="radio4" value="1" /> <br />
No
<input class="calc" type="radio" name="radio4" value="0" /> <br />
N/A
<input class="calc" type="radio" name="radio4" value="0" /> <br />

</form> 
</td>
  </tr>
   
  </table>
  
  </body>
</html>
---------------------------------------
Last html Page
 
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<table>
<tr>
    <th>COMPLIANCE AND AUDIT</th>
   
  </tr>
  
  <
  <tr>
    <td>54. Do you review and revise your security documents, such as: policies,
standards, procedures, and guidelines, on a regular basis?
<form>
 Yes
<input class="calc" type="radio" name="radio4" value="1" /> <br />
No
<input class="calc" type="radio" name="radio4" value="0" /> <br />
N/A
<input class="calc" type="radio" name="radio4" value="0" /> <br />

</form> 
</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>55. Do you audit your processes and procedures for compliance with established
policies and standards? 

<form>
 Yes
<input class="calc" type="radio" name="radio4" value="1" /> <br />
No
<input class="calc" type="radio" name="radio4" value="0" /> <br />
N/A
<input class="calc" type="radio" name="radio4" value="0" /> <br />

</form> 
</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>56. Do you test your disaster plans on a regular basis?
<form>
 Yes
<input class="calc" type="radio" name="radio4" value="1" /> <br />
No
<input class="calc" type="radio" name="radio4" value="0" /> <br />
N/A
<input class="calc" type="radio" name="radio4" value="0" /> <br />

</form> 
</td>
  </tr>

  </table>

<a href="secEdu.html" class="previous">&laquo; Previous</a>
 <input type="hidden" name="total" id="total" />
    <input id="submitted" type="Submit" value="Submit"><br><br>
    <p id="demo"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: All your radio buttons have the same name, so they're part of the same group.

Comment: *"pass the values to throughout the 5 html pages"* - How are you currently achieving this?

Comment: if you are changing the page without submitting the form you would have to store it to a cookie or other local variable. You may want to consider hiding and/or showing fieldsets in stages and submitting from ONE single html page. Google Multi-step form there are tons of jquery examples

Answer (score 0):

Store in localstorage and get it from all other pages. 
Ex : `localstorage.setItem("RadioVal",'true');`

get from localstorage in other scripts and assign in appropriate html fields.
Ex : `var radio1 = localstorage.getItem("RadioVal");`